# 3DS Max 2010 x86 Bad Quality Background Image

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax

When i use background image from [the-blueprits.com](https://www.the-blueprints.com/blueprints/humans/humans/32708/view/athletic_male/) in 3ds max 2010 x86 for viewport background or plane (by material) object type the image quality so bad look like this? 
please any advice how to normalize it??

[image]
<sub>(source: [kaskus.com](http://cdn.kaskus.com/images/2014/02/25/5732667_20140225084708.png))</sub>

Comment: Well, this is preview mode, basically. Did you try rendering that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 3dsmax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to: Customize -> Preferences... ->  Viewports tab  -> Configure Driver   (only if driver is Direct3D or OpenGL)

Set these:

Background textures Size: 1024

Match Bitmap Size as Closely as Possible: check

Download Texture size: 512

Match Bitmap Size as Closely as Possible: check

Then reload the texture in the Material Editor